# MVC create N dropdown box dynamically in Razor Page View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I would create a View page that has initially a dropDownBox.
When the user will change the dropDownBox's initial value, the application will create a new dropdownbox with the same values.

How can i make it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is encouraged to have a go first and post any problems you have along the way. Thanks

Comment: I've added in the view this code:

<input type="button" onclick="Add()" value="Add Medicine" />
<div id="content" class="form-group"></div>

    
    <script>
        function Add() {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML +=
                "@Html.DropDownList("medicine", ViewBag.medicine as SelectList)";
        }
    </script>